# Is there a reward for collecting all of the stars in Super Mario Galaxy?

Tags: super-mario-galaxy

Does anything interesting happen when you collect all of the stars in Super Mario Galaxy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get to play as Luigi, the controls are a bit less easy to handle. He runs faster and jumps higher, but he is harder to stop. You can then get all the stars all over again.

Believe me, it's kinda difficult to get all the stars.

Comment: What happens once you earn them all again?

Comment: You get to go to the grand finale galaxy with 100 purple coins, giving you the 121st star. That's all there is to the game.

Comment: Note that Grand Finale Galaxy is playable as both Mario and Luigi, bringing the grand total up to 242 stars.

Answer (score -2):

No, nothing exciting happens. You unlock the Luigi feature at a certain point, but you don't need all the stars. Sorry to disappoint you. :(

Comment: You actually do need all the stars.

Comment: I had 105 stars at a point and I had not got Luigi.